# Изменить имя координат matplotlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Сразу к вопросу: при построении графиков с помощью библиотеки `matplotlib` для *Python* можно задать подписи осей, но в правом нижнем углу координаты имена остаются **х** и **у**, можно ли как-то изменить имена этих координат?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

xn = [1,2,3] 
yn = [1,4,9] 
plt.xlabel('t') 
plt.ylabel('f') 
plt.plot(xn, yn) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xn = [1,2,3]
yn = [1,4,9]

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('f')
plt.plot(xn, yn)
plt.show()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181328/4804629

Answer (score 1):

> Axes.format_coord(self, x, y)
>
> Вернуть строку формата, форматирующую координаты x, y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
xn = [1,2,3] 
yn = [1,4,9] 

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y : 'x-coordinate = ' + format(x, '1.4f') + ', ' + \
                                'y-coordinate = ' + format(y, '1.4f')

plt.xlabel('t') 
plt.ylabel('f') 
plt.plot(xn, yn) 
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]